# teraterm（Linuxのコマンドライン）で.7zファイルを展開・閲覧・管理方法について教えてください。

Tags: linux, windows, xml

（Stack Overflow metaの方でも質問させていただきました．以下は質問内容です．）

拡張子が.7zのファイルの解凍し閲覧したいと考えています。
現在teratermを使っています。
たとえば展開したいファイルとしましてstack exchange data dumpの右側に表示されているdownload optionの７Zと表示されている中の.7zファイルです。
それらの277ファイルをteratermに移行する方法、閲覧する方法を詳しく教えてください。

stack exchange data dumpのURL↓
https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

使用するデータ
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

関連する質問
1.[Stack Exchange Data Explorer の使い方を教えてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1953/stack-exchange-data-explorer-%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/1954#1954)
2.[stack overflowの公開データについて利用法やデータ詳細やどのような形で提供されているか等を教えていただきたい（API以外の方法も希望する）](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1947/stack-overflow%E3%81%AE%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E6%B3%95%E3%82%84%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E3%82%84%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E5%BD%A2%E3%81%A7%E6%8F%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E7%AD%89%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-api%E4%BB%A5%E5%A4%96%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%82%82%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/1948?noredirect=1#comment1161_1948)
3.[Stack Exchange Data Explorer の使い方を教えてください](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1953/stack-exchange-data-explorer-%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/1954#1954)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

展開方法は[過去の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1958/)で回答があったようなので、ダウンロード方法の例のみ示します。
テスト目的であれば`--accept=japanese.stackexchange.com.7z`などで十分かもしれませんね。

```
wget --recursive --continue --no-parent --level=1 --accept=.7z https://archive.org/download/stackexchange
```

Answer (score 4):

まずそもそも。
teraterm は、回線で繋がったPCへログインして操作するためのツールです。
ですので、 teraterm へのデータの移行という表現はおかしく、(接続先の) linux へのデータの移行を意味しているのだと理解しました。

また同時に、そうだとするとやりたいことは linux 上に対象の .7z ファイルを配置することであると理解できます。だとすると、linux 上で web から直接取得した方が早いので、 mjy さんがその方法を説明しています。

また、.7z ファイルを展開する方法は、 mjy さんが示しているリンク先にあるコマンドを実行すれば、中身を展開できます。具体的には、`7z x name.7z`です。`7z`がインストールされてないことによるエラーが発生した場合は、`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` を実行します。

どうやら、xml ファイルが取得できるようですが、これをteraterm から閲覧するのであれば、端末上で動くテキストビューワー・エディターなどを用いてテキストファイルとして閲覧するのが常套だと思います。

その目的では、`less`をお勧めします。`less TARGETFILE`で対象ファイルのテキストが表示されます。
スペースで進む、`b`で戻る、`q`で終了です。

Answer (score 1):

SSH限定ですが

**ローカルPCからリモートホストにファイル転送する方法**

1. Teraterm でリモートホストにSSH で接続
2. ファイル → SSH SCP を選ぶ
3. `From:` にローカルPCのファイルパスを記述
4. `To:` にリモートホストの転送先パスを記述
5. `Send` ボタンを押す

するとリモートホスト上にファイルがコピーされます。

逆方向の場合は

**リモートホストからローカルPCにファイル転送する方法**

1. Teraterm でリモートホストにSSH で接続
2. ファイル → SSH SCP を選ぶ
3. `From:` にリモートホストのファイルパスを記述
4. `To:` にローカルPCの保存先パスを記述
5. `Receive` ボタンを押す

`From:` と `To:` が二箇所ずつあるのでボタンの位置で判断してください。